# Listing , pagination and search custom user data by role in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

You can list,search and implement pagination easily by using below script.
Thanks,

Comment: The question is? If you wanted to add the code, you could do it under [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/topics), or use gist on github...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   <?php

        if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
        }

        $search_term = sanitize_text_field($_GET['s']);

        $only_fields = array( 'user_login', 'user_nicename', 'user_email','ID' );
        $count_args  = array(
                'role'      => 'enter-custom-user-role',
                'fields'    => $only_fields,
                'search'    => '*'.esc_attr( $search_term ).'*',
                'number'    => 999999

        );

        $user_count_query = new WP_User_Query($count_args);
        $user_count = $user_count_query->get_results();

        // count the number of users found in the query
        $total_users = $user_count ? count($user_count) : 1;

        // grab the current page number and set to 1 if no page number is set
        $page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 1;

        // how many users to show per page
        $users_per_page = 5;

        // calculate the total number of pages.
        $total_pages = 1;
        $offset      = $users_per_page * ($page - 1);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_users / $users_per_page);

        $user_fields =  array( 'user_login', 'user_nicename', 'user_email','ID' );

        // main user query
        $args  = array(
                // search only for Authors role
                'role'      => 'enter-custom-user-role',
                // order results by display_name
                'orderby'   => 'display_name',
                // return all fields
                'fields'    => $user_fields,
                'number'    => $users_per_page,
                'order'     => 'ASC',
                'search'    => '*'.esc_attr( $search_term ).'*',
                'offset'    => $offset // skip the number of users that we have per page
        );

        // Create the WP_User_Query object
        $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);

        // Get the results
        $all_agents = $wp_user_query->get_results();

        // grab the current query parameters
        $query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

        // The $base variable stores the complete URL to our page, including the current page arg

        // if in the admin, your base should be the admin URL + your page
        $base = admin_url('admin.php') . '?' . remove_query_arg('p', $query_string) . '%_%';
        ?>
        <form method="get" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php');?>">
            <p class="search-box">
                <label class="screen-reader-text" for="user-search-input">Search Users:</label>
                <input type="search" id="user-search-input" name="s" value="">
                <input type="hidden" id="user-search-input" name="page" value="bespoke_registered_agent">
                <input type="submit" id="search-submit" class="button" value="Search Users">
            </p>

            <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped users">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" id="username" class="manage-column column-name">Username</th>
                        <th scope="col" id="email" class="manage-column column-email">Email</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="the-list" data-wp-lists="list:user">
                    <?php if(!empty($all_agents)){
                    foreach($all_agents as $key => $agent){
                        $username       =   $agent->user_login;
                        $useremail      =   $agent->user_email;
                        $agentid        =   $agent->ID;

                    $profile_url = get_user_meta($agentid,'profile_picture',true);
                    if(empty($profile_url)){
                        $profile_url = BHD_GET_DIR_URL.'assets/images/no-photo-available-icon.jpg';
                    }


                    ?>
                    <tr id="user-<?php echo $agentid; ?>">
                        <td class="username column-username has-row-actions column-primary" data-colname="Username">
                            <img alt="" src="<?php echo $profile_url;?>" class="avatar avatar-32 photo" height="32" width="32"> 
                            <strong>                                
                            </strong><br>

                        </td>
                        <td class="email column-email" data-colname="Email"><a href="mailto:<?php echo $useremail?>"><?php echo $useremail;?></a></td>

                    </tr>

                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <tr class="no-items"><td class="colspanchange" colspan="3">No users found.</td></tr>
                    <?php }?>       
                </tbody>

                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="manage-column column-name">Username</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="manage-column column-email">Email</th>

                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php // if on the front end, your base is the current page
        //$base = get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '?' . remove_query_arg('p', $query_string) . '%_%';
        echo '<div id="pagination" class="tablenav-pages">';
        echo paginate_links( array(
                'base'      => $base, // the base URL, including query arg
                'format'    => '&p=%#%', // this defines the query parameter that will be used, in this case "p"
                'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Previous'), // text for previous page
                'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'), // text for next page
                'total'     => $total_pages, // the total number of pages we have
                'current'   => $page, // the current page
                'end_size'  => 1,
                'mid_size'  => 5,
        ));
        echo '</div>';

        ?>
```